# facebook login and posting error

Tags: android, facebook

**i am trying to post a sample message on facebook wall by clicking a button.the below code crashes when the login page is displayed and showing errors:**

05-07 20:22:39.843: E/AndroidRuntime(810): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 20:22:39.843: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.facebook.android.SessionStore.save(SessionStore.java:33)
05-07 20:22:39.843: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.test.fb.TestPost$FbLoginDialogListener.onComplete(TestPost.java:116)
05-07 20:22:39.843: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.onComplete(Facebook.java:308)
05-07 20:22:39.843: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.facebook.android.FbDialog$FbWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(FbDialog.java:125)

any help is appriciated.
thanks

```
package com.test.fb;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.BaseRequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.SessionStore;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;


public class TestPost extends Activity{
    private TestPost _activity;
    private Facebook mFacebook;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    private Handler mRunOnUi = new Handler();
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"};
    private static final String APP_ID = "331862293507865";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //final EditText reviewEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.revieew);
        //mFacebookCb                 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_facebook);

        mProgress   = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mFacebook   = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);


        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mFacebook.isSessionValid()){

                String review = "Sample post";

                if (review.equals(""))
                    return;
                 postToFacebook(review);
                }
                else{
                    onFacebookClick();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void onFacebookClick() {
        if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
            postToFacebook(null);
                } else {
            mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, -1, new FbLoginDialogListener());
        }
    }
    private void postToFacebook(String review) {    
        mProgress.setMessage("Posting ...");
        mProgress.show();

        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();

        params.putString("message", review);
        params.putString("name", "Dexter");
        params.putString("caption", "londatiga.net");
        params.putString("link", "http://www.londatiga.net");
        params.putString("description", "Dexter, seven years old dachshund who loves to catch cats, eat carrot and krupuk");
        params.putString("picture", "http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44");

        mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new WallPostListener());
    }

    private final class WallPostListener extends BaseRequestListener {
        public void onComplete(final String response) {
            mRunOnUi.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    mProgress.cancel();

                    Toast.makeText(TestPost.this, "Posted to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private final class FbLoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            SessionStore.save(mFacebook, _activity);
           getFbName();
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {

        }

        public void onError(DialogError error) {

        }

        public void onCancel() {

        }
    }
    private void getFbName() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Finalizing ...");
        mProgress.show();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String name = "";
                int what = 1;

                try {
                    String me = mFacebook.request("me");

                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(me).nextValue();
                    name = jsonObj.getString("email");
                    what = 0;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                mFbHandler.sendMessage(mFbHandler.obtainMessage(what, name));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private Handler mFbHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            mProgress.dismiss();

            if (msg.what == 0) {
                String username = (String) msg.obj;
                username = (username.equals("")) ? "No Name" : username;

                SessionStore.saveName(username, _activity);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(_activity, "Connected to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *onComplete* method you are trying to save the session:

```
SessionStore.save(mFacebook, _activity);
```

The problem, I think, is that you haven't assigned any value to the "_activity" parameter (in the code you posted) and so it's null.

What's the point of this variable anyhow? If it's to gain access to the activity instance from within the private class then you can try:

```
SessionStore.save(mFacebook, TestPost.this);
```